# How to retrieve value from attribute in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, windows-phone-7

**What I have:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" standalone="yes"?>
<FiberItems>
    <Fiber China="1a" England="1b"  Japan="1c"  France="1d" Korea="1e"/>
    <Fiber China="2a" England="2b"  Japan="2c"  France="2d" Korea="2e"/>
</FiberItems>
```

**What I want:**
1.retrive all the value of "China" into a string array.
2.if a value of China is "1a", retrive all the value of the rest attributes(1b,1c,1d,1e),.

**What I do:**
1. I write codes for purpose 1 , but never works >_<

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("/FiberItems.xml");
        IEnumerable<string> query = from fiber in doc.Root.Elements("Fiber")
                                    select (string)fiber.Attribute("China");

        string[] myString = new string[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            foreach (string item in query)
            {
                myString[i] = (string)item;
            }
        }
```

2. for purpose 2, have no idea yet >_<

need helps

Comment: Describe what _"never works"_ means. Errors, empty results? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: always retrive the last element, mystring[0] ="2a";mystring[1]="2a";

Comment: Take a look at LinqToXml, it is quite easy.

Comment: *How* do you want the attributes? Just as a sequence of them? Would it always be keyed by the China attribute?

Comment: grab them into a string[] or a string list @_@

Comment: :( sorry for that, Tilak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use an array to collect your data but when you do:

```
    string[] myString = new string[3];
  //  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  //  {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string item in query)
        {
            myString[i] = (string)item;
            i += 1;
        }
  //  }
```

You are doing 3x3 rounds where only 3 are needed.

Answer (score 0):

So your requirement is if the attribute China value is "1a" then get all the attribute value of that node. I think it should work

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("/FiberItems.xml");
IEnumerable<string> query = from fiber in doc.Root.Elements("Fiber")
                            //condition 1
                            where (string)fiber.Attribute("China") == "1a"
                            //condition 2 : Select all except china attribute
                            select fiber.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name !="China");
```

Comment: for condition 1: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute' and 'string'

Comment: Ah, missed the obvious cast. It should be..
where (string)fiber.Attribute("China") == "1a"
I have updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
        XDocument root = XDocument.Load("/FiberItems.xml");
        var attributesChina = root.Elements("FiberItems").Elements("Fiber").Attributes("China");
        // attributesChina will contain all the values of china
        foreach (XAttribute china in attributesChina)
        {
            string value = china.value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load XML element
XElement root = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText("/FiberItems.xml")); 

//All china attributes (retrieves 1a,2a)
var chinaAttributes= root.Elements().Attributes("China");

//load all rest attributes for china = 1a, loads 1b,1c,1d,1e
var chinaOneARestAttributes = root.Elements().Where(a=>a.Attribute("China")!=null && a.Attribute("China").Value=="1a").Attributes().Select(x=>x.Value).Where(x=>!String.Equals(x,"1a"));
```

UPDATED for Null Reference Exception. With the data i had tried earlier, i ensured Attribute China was present for all elements.

Comment: a.Attribute("China").Value=="1a"[NullReferenceException] :(

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML:

```
var xmlStr = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""Unicode"" standalone=""yes""?>
<FiberItems>
    <Fiber China=""1a"" England=""1b""  Japan=""1c""  France=""1d"" Korea=""1e""/>
    <Fiber China=""2a"" England=""2b""  Japan=""2c""  France=""2d"" Korea=""2e""/>
</FiberItems>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var query =
    from fiber in doc.Descendants("Fiber")
    where (string)fiber.Attribute("China") == "1a"
    select String.Join(", ",
        (from attr in fiber.Attributes()
         where attr.Name != "China"
         select (string)attr).ToArray());
```

This will return a sequence of the other attribute values for each `Fiber` element that contains a `China` attribute with the value `1a`.

Comment: When I try to grab the query into a List<string> with this code [List<string> mylist = query.ToList();],an error pops up,[Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'],how to?

Comment: I made adjustments to make it return that sequence as a string... try it again.

Comment: Thanks again!!! spend a whole night and finally solve it! I will do my homework at the rest time :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out System.Xml.Linq.

Here's an example to get a list of all the attributes for one element.

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""Unicode"" standalone=""yes""?>
<FiberItems>
<Fiber China=""1a"" England=""1b""  Japan=""1c""  France=""1d"" Korea=""1e""/>
<Fiber China=""2a"" England=""2b""  Japan=""2c""  France=""2d"" Korea=""2e""/>
</FiberItems>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement ele = doc.Root.Element("Fiber");
var att = ele.Attributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

In XPath:

```
/FiberItems/Fiber[@China='1a']/@*
```

gets you all the attributes of Fiber elements with China='1a' and

```
/FiberItems/Fiber[@China='1a']/@*[local-name()!='China']
```

gets you the same sequence of attributes excluding the China attribute.